# Django formset - not setting initial data when data is passed

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am creating form using Django Form wizard and formsets.

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
initial_data_set = []
for x in some_list:
     initial_data_set.append({
                        'title' : x.title,
                    })
data = {
'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '5',
'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '5',
'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
 }
formset_class = formset_factory(TitleForm, extra =0)
formset =  formset_class(data=data, initial=initial_data_set)
return formset
```

Template

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n %}


{% block content %}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form.media }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endif %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {% if ingestable_upload %}
            <tr>{{ form.as_inline_table }}</tr>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "Submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I was able to see initial data in my form when I was not passing 'data'. However, not passing data was giving me formset.is_valid as False and there was None in the cleaned_data. So I created data{} and passed it as per the documentation here - 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Since I started passing data, form is not getting populated with initial data.
I have put debug statements in formsets.py under BaseFormSet() class. It is getting both data and initial data that I am passing.

I have been struggling with this for few days. Any help on how I can populate my form and get cleaned data will be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is overriding your form initial data with your data object, data attribute is not necessary that data is passed on the `{{ formset.management_form }}` in your template.

There's something else wrong with your form. I would suggest you print the errors when is_valid fails and see what's missing.

Comment: I did that. It was complaining about form is not bound. And in BaseFormSet the isBound is set like this -  self.is_bound = data is not None or files is not None. So I started passing data so that my form gets bound. In is_valid the first thing it checks is if self.is_bound == true. if not it returns false.

Comment: Can you share the view and template where you handle the POST?

Comment: Updated the original post. Also when I am doing print "Formset data {} {}".format(formset.data, formset.as_table()) as_table is printing rows without initial data.